# Getting error in c++ conversion from int to non scalar type 'point':

Tags: c++, c++14

1.in this code i want to construct an array of point type and initialize its value of each index as 1,2

can i achieve the following code???

2.what is the correct method to do that if the following code doesn't work ???

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class point
{
 private:
   int x,y;
 public:
   point(int a,int b)
   {
       cout<<"constructor called here"<<endl;
       x=a;
       y=b;
   }
};

int main()
{
point p[2]{(1,2),(1,2)}; 
}
```

Comment: perhaps point p[2] = {(1,2),(1,2)}; ? Also your question is a potential duplicate if that solves your issue

Answer (score 5):

You should use `{}` instead of `()`:

```
point p[2]{{1,2}, {1,2}};
```

or use class name:

```
point p[2]{point(1,2), point(1,2)};
```

Comment: okay but how can i print the p[1] ??? i have tried writing a seperate print function in class that gives nothing

Comment: Just create a function accepting a point type object and use cout. Call that in main.

Comment: Which is the problem? No problem  [Here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15433d6eb8d0f8e6)

Answer (score 1):

Use parantheses `{ }` not `()`.

There are various ways to display the points, for instance create a function:

- which simply displays the class members:<sup>1</sup>

```cpp
void display() { std::cout<<x<<" "<<y; }
```

- which accepts a point type object and displays the same:<sup>2</sup>

```cpp
friend void display(point p) { std::cout<<p.x<<" "<<p.y; }
```

Call them in `main`:

```cpp
int main()
{
   point p[2]{{1,2},{2,1}}; 

   // method 1:
   p[0].display(); // 1 2
   p[1].display(); // 2 1

   // method 2:
   display(p[0]); // 1 2
   display(p[1]); // 2 1
}
```

Comment: Either create free function take point, or use member function without parameter. so call `display(p[0]);` or `p[0].display();`.

Comment: You already did that so am posting an alternative, by passing the object. I'll edit the possible list of options tho, wait.

Comment: `friend` `display` to allow `display(p[0])` or `static`: `point::display(p[0])`.

Comment: @walnut Ah I see..I was wondering if my approach was wrong. I agree its unnecessary to provide the argument twice. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarod42 After walnut's point I understand why you gave me those options. Thanks, Hope it is correct now :)